# insert xml stream into pdf/a names tree using itext7 and c#

Tags: xml, tree, itext7, names, pdfa

I included an xml file into a pdf/a2 using itext7 and c#.

The xml stream has been inserted into the pdf names tree as XFAResource.

Everything seems to be ok, but comparing my pdf file with a pdf used as an example I note a litle difference in the  stream length type.

In my pdf the length is just an integer value, in the master pdf is an object with a length parameter which contains the integer value.

I do not have any idea how to fix it.

Here my code and the names tree screen shot (itext-rups) of the 2 pdf that better point out the differences.

Thank you to everybody has a clue.

Mauro

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Pdfa;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PdfXml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pdfIn = "\\xfar\\pdfin.pdf";
            string pdfOut = "\\xfar\\pdfoutU.pdf";
            string cdaIn = "\\xfar\\cda.xml";
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(cdaIn);
                var content = new StringBuilder();
                string line;
                while (Reader.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    line = Reader.ReadLine();
                    content.AppendLine(line);
                }
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content.ToString());             
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfIn), new PdfWriter(pdfOut));            
                PdfStream stream = new PdfStream();;
                PdfNameTree nameTree1 = pdfDoc.GetCatalog().GetNameTree(new PdfName("XFAResource"));
                stream.SetCompressionLevel(9);
                stream.SetData(bytes, true);
                nameTree1.AddEntry("dataset", stream);
                nameTree1.BuildTree();
                nameTree1.SetModified();
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
                }                
              pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[screen shot of the names tree:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdlNy.png)

[image]

Comment: Those two representation styles are equivalent. Do you really need the more cumbersome variant used in your master pdf?

Comment: @mklI made
the pdf according to a public healthcare organisation specification which accept and validate it.
The validation process rise an error extracting the XAResource Dictionary Object.
Before claim with them that the xml is exactly in the same position as in the master pdf, I wondering how to reproduce exactly the same "cumbersome" names tree structure.

Comment: Please consider fixing other differences first, e.g. your file the **XFAResource** element **Names** array starts with "dataset" (singular) while in the master document it starts with "datasets" (plural). This is a real difference, those strings are not equivalent.

Comment: @mkl
YOU ARE GREAT!!
That was exactly the problem, the file has been validated.
I double checked everything but I didn't note the stupid s.
Thank you very much.

Comment: MauroCorti, Please write an answer to your own question including @mkl s Comment